# My Login method doesn't comparing email and password in database why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2

This my Login Method in Repository Class Where i'm writing a logic to check the email id and password that will matches already registered user in the database and returns true if the email and password matched in db

```
    public bool Login(Models.Login user)
    {
        Eseal.UserRegister u = null;
        try
        {
            string Dpassword = Decrypt(user.Password);
            using (var dbContext = new MVCDEMOEntities())
            {
                u = dbContext.UserRegisters.Where(query => query.EmailID.Equals(user.EmailID) && query.Password.Equals(user.Password)).SingleOrDefault();
            }
            if (u == null)
                return false
            else
                return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
     }
```

This my Account Controller code

```
public ActionResult Login(Models.Login user)
    {
       try
        {
            var services = new RegisterService();
            services.LoginRegister(user);

            return RedirectToAction("Privacy");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

### This is my save register method

```
  public string SaveRegister(Models.UserRegister model)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dbcontext = new MVCDEMOEntities())
            {
                var dbRegister = new Eseal.UserRegister()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Password = encrypt(model.Password),
                    EmailID = model.EmailID,
                    ContactNumber = model.ContactNumber,
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                    CreatedBy = 1,
                    UpdatedOn=null,
                    UpdatedBy=null,
                    IsExists= true
                 };

                dbcontext.UserRegisters.Add(dbRegister);
                dbcontext.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
```

### This is my Service Class

```
public void LoginRegister(Models.Login user)
    {
        var result = _repository.Login(user);
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug the code `u == null` true? Can you share the code of `LoginRegister` method too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

Comment: u is showing null sir

Comment: DPassword is the db saved password and user.password is the user entered password

Comment: You saving encrypted password `Password = encrypt(model.Password)`, then you compare password provided by user model with encrypted password in the database record. Does `user.Password` in `Login` encrypted as well?

Comment: But you compare plane text with encrypted password in database.

Comment: @ Fabio you are correct how to comapre with encrypted password

Comment: You need encrypt given plain text password before comparing with password in the database

Comment: @ Fabio ok but it's should show error rite for that. but it's loging in why?

Comment: do encrypt outside of your LINQ query.

Comment: it's logging into admin page

Comment: controller is calling services class first, then services class calling this method, this method is wrote in Repository

Comment: Can you talk us through why you rolled your own security model rather than use the inbuilt framework forms authentication?

Comment: I just wanted to do the project in repository pattern so i did my own security model @mjwills

Comment: I would strongly suggest you not do this. The amount of time you have spent on this suggests the built in way (which works, and is more secure) would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You compare encrypted password in database against plain text password provided by user.

You should encrypt plain password before comparing it with password in database.

```
public bool Login(Models.Login user)
{
    var encryptedGivenPassword = encrypt(user.Password);
    using (var dbContext = new MVCDEMOEntities())
    {
        return dbContext.UserRegisters.Where(u => u.EmailID == user.EmailID)
                                      .Where(u => u.Password == encryptedGivenPassword)
                                      .Any();
    }
 }
```

Your service method should return result of `Login` method

```
public bool LoginRegister(Models.Login user) 
{ 
    return _repository.Login(user); 
}
```

Then you call this method in the login controller

```
public ActionResult Login(Models.Login user)
{
   var services = new RegisterService();
   if (services.Login(user))
   {
       return RedirectToAction("Privacy");
   }
   else
   {
       return Unathorized();
   }
}
```

You can get rid of you redundant `try .. catch` wrappers.

Comment: the code you modified also not working. it's working if the user is not registered also.

Comment: @NiranjanS, You need to call `Login` method in the controller. I afraid that when you call `LoginRegister` you will register new user instead of just validate it.

Comment: public void LoginRegister(Models.Login user)
        {
            var result = _repository.Login(user);
        }            I am calling Login Method in Service layer

Comment: @NiranjanS, you need return result of `Login` method back to controller, that you can return correct View based on that result.

Comment: Can You Please @Fabio send me any reference links of code or please tell me where to modified my code. because i am new to MVC